# How to save Outlook attachment in a drive with a new name and overwrite if it already exists?

Tags: scripting, vba

I am using below VBA script to download attachments from email and save it to my windows directory.
I need help to modify this script - 1) to save rename the attachment before saving it 2) Overwrite the file if it already exists. Kindly help.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
sSaveFolder = "F:\RBL Attachments\"
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim obj As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "D:\EmailAttachments"
     For Each obj In itm.Attachments
          obj.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & obj.DisplayName
          Set obj = Nothing
     Next
End Sub
```